# sql query to selecting first 3 rows as according to set and remaning should select normaly

Tags: mysql, sql

How to work with sql query to selecting first  3 rows as according to set value(status = 1) and remaining should select according to descending order..

suppose i have table 'table1' which have  '9'  rows
e.g 
sn and status
1->0 ,2->0, 3->1, 4->0, 5->1, 6->0, 7->0, 8->0, 9->1

I need first three should be according to status '1' and remaining '6' rows as normal...
out put will be
3
5
9
first three comes according to staus 1
and ohere are 
1
2
4
6
7
8
o/p
3
5
9
1
2
4
6
7
8

Comment: Please give some more detail like **Table structure, Data Prensent in table**.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Please spend a few minutes read [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) on how ask questions and provide detailed information about your table, relevant sample data and desired output based that on it. Showing what you've tried so far would also be nice so that we see your effort.

Comment: suppose i have table 'table1' which have  '9'  rows
e.g 
sn and status
1->0 ,2->0, 3->1, 4->0, 5->1, 6->0, 7->0, 8->0, 9->1

I need first three should be according to status '1' and remaining '6' rows as normal...
out put will be
3
5
9
first three comes according to staus 1
and othere are 
1
2
4
6
7
8 thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
Select sn,status
From myTable
Order By status DESC,sn
```